# Why do I receive an 'undefined' in addition to my correct output in JavaScript? I would like to get rid off "undefined"

Tags: javascript, undefined, javascript-objects

I have a huge object that is defined as

`var success;`

Then I access this object properties as follows:

`var title = success.categories.cms.results[0].title;`
`console.log(title);`
`var company1 = success.categories.cms.results[0].company[0];`
`console.log(company1);`

and so on. I can tell that the way I access object properties is correct because I get back the correct values in the console. But I have no idea why I also receive 'undefined' value after the correct value.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you also attach the JSON you are trying to parse.

Comment: Don't look at those console undefined. **Console.log returns undefined** and which is get printed. You should not be bothered about that.

Answer (score 1):

coz function console.log() returns undefined value